# Publish Facebook app in fanpage

Tags: facebook, tabs, publish, facebook-page

We developed a facebook tab application. It is submitted but we got this message: Your App Detail page is live and available in search. Your app does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be approved for listing in the App Center at this time. How can we get positive ratings and engagement if only admin and developers can see the application? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really wanna submit app to app center? Your app will work well without it, moreover - appcenter is designed for canvas application. If you wanna make your application accessible for everyone, just disable sanbox mode.